# Fastest way to display data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i want to load a table with around 10k entries into a div once the page has loaded.
I use the body onload funtion to make an ajax request that reads data from 10k different text files, parse the data into a table, and return the table to the div.
but it takes a lot of time to read and parse data from 10k files.
I've tried simultaneous parsing using javascript, but it still requires php functions so all i can do is make parallel AJAX requests,
but that doesnt seem to do the job either.

What could be the best/fastest way to display the table??

the JSON

```
{  
   "InventionTitle":"Method and system using information",
   "Abstract":"This invention provides assistance to a user in accessing network attached information sources.",
   "number1":"US-6102969-A",
   "date1":"19990512",
   "date2":"20000815",
   "number2":"US-09310899",
   "has_pdf":"",
   "TitleDWPI":"",
   "AbstractDWPI":"",
   "Assignees":"TkVUQk9U",
   "Inventors":"Q0hSSVNUSUFOU09OIERBVklE | RE9PUkVOQk9TIFJPQkVSVCBC",
   "PriorityNums":"US-08933782 | US-08025304",
   "PriorityDates":"19970919 | 19960920",
   "IPCClasses":"G06F 13/00 | G06F 17/30",
   "ECLAClasses":"H04L 29/08N1 | G06F 17/30W1",
   "USClasses":"717/146 | 707/999.002 | 707/999.01",
   "CPCClasses":"Y10S 707/99933 | Y10S 707/99935 | Y10S 707/99944"
}
```

table rows are
Title, number1, number2, date1, date2, inventor, assignee

Comment: Try loading the table a little bit at a time. Use your AJAX to load a row as it parses the data, then move onto the next, instead of build the entire table and then dropping it in.

Comment: Pagination would be your friend... as AoN states, it would be better to build the table bit by bit. No one will want or be able to read the full table in a second.

Comment: A table with 10k rows(?) will be slow to even _render_ by the browser, even if you transfered it the “classic” way, without using AJAX. If you can use a fixed table width, so that the browser does not have to calculate it based on the content of every single cell, that might speed rendering up. Btw., getting that mass amount of data thrown at them in one go might not be the most helpful thing for the user either – maybe you should think about pagination and search/filtering of the data beforehand instead.

Comment: i've tried that too, but the problem is, i need all the data for the other functionalities of the page to work. I need to show/hide these table entries but since all the rows dont load at once, the function cannot show/hide the rows that aren't even present

Comment: pagination isnt an option either. i need to do filtering on the table rows, so pagination will prevent me from doing so

Comment: what if i save the complete prepared table in a separate file and load it whenever i go the that page. But i know it will drastically increase the space required. and will increase redundancy.

Comment: Can you provide me with a sample json and a sample table row? I am displaying about 10.000 rows in a custom multi colum select box and I think I can modify my code for your needs.

Comment: json and sample table added

Comment: @nullvoid Pagination, if done with scripting, wouldn't hinder the ability to filter/sort data. In fact, it would likely help you. Basically, you would have the script create links based upon the number of rows (10,000 / 100 per page = 100 page links). It loads the first page and begins to load the remaining as I suggested above. If you switch pages, you then force that page to load before continue to load the rest. Basically, it's a highly complex set-up, and I can't think of any reason 10k rows would ever be needed to load on a page.

Answer (score 0):

use settimeout in js to create asynchronous behaviour and pull a little bit of data in chunks instead.

http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-large-data-processing/

http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-timer-pseudo-threading/

Comment: @ʰᵈˑOP didn't provide much code. This is quite a good answer to what the OP wants.